# Increase or decrease learning rate for adding neurons or weights?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a convolutional neural network of which I modified the architecture. I do not have time to retrain and perform a cross-validation (grid search over optimal parameters). I want to *intuitively adjust* the learning rate.

Should I *increase* or *decrease* the learning rate of my RMS (SGD-based) optimiser if:

1. I add *more* neurons to the fully connected layers?
2. on a convolutional neural network, I remove a sub-sampling (average or max pooling) layer before the full connections, and I increase the amount of fully connected units between that feature map and the softmax outputs (so that there are *more* weights connected to the fully connected neurons on top)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a short and **practical** answer, here the learning rate is decreased if the model is more complex, the variable `model_size` is approximately the number of neurons per layer:

```
def rate(self, step = None):
    "Implement `lrate` above"
    if step is None:
        step = self._step
    return self.factor * \
        (self.model_size ** (-0.5) *
        min(step ** (-0.5), step * self.warmup ** (-1.5)))
```

Source: [The Annotated Transformer](https://github.com/harvardnlp/annotated-transformer/blob/master/The%20Annotated%20Transformer.ipynb)

Also see: [Adam: A Method for Stochastic Optimization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6980)

Comment: Note: this is "the" answer I'd have liked to have before. Sorry for self-accepting my own answer years later. But this is it.

Answer (score 11):

Well adding more layers/neurons increases the chance of over-fitting. Therefore it would be better if you decrease the learning rate over time. Removing the subsampling layers also increases the number of parameters and again the chance to over-fit. It is highly recommended, proven through empirical results at least, that subsampling layers can help the model learn better significantly. So avoid removing them.

Also I suggest you generate more examples by cropping the images and train the model with those cropped versions too. This works as a regularizer helps the model learn a better distribution of the data. Then you can also increase the number of layers/neurons with less risk of over-fitting.

Comment: So here in both case, adding regularisation and decreasing the learning rate is a good idea. Thanks.

Comment: Why should having a higher chance of overfitting (due to more parameters) mean that you should decrease the learning rate over time?  How does decreasing the learning rate help solve the overfitting problem?

Comment: @Peter not necessarily. Since adding more layers/nodes to the model makes it prone to over-fitting, large changes for the parameter values could potentially lead to over-fitting or diverge from the solution. In such cases taking small steps towards the local minima is recommended and the learning rate controls the step size to move.

Comment: @Amir What's the source on that?  It's the statement "large changes for the parameter values could potentially lead to over-fitting" that I'm skeptical of/don't understand.

Comment: To my knowledge, as (I think) @Peter suggests, decreasing learning rate over time helps only to ensure a good convergence rate (converges faster at the beginning and doesn't diverge in later iterations). However, it doesn't avoid overfitting. I might be wrong though.

Comment: @Peter what I meant was you may end of somewhere in the parameter space with a higher chance of over-fitting. However, in most cases large learning rates usually leads to bad model performance (weights divergence)

Answer (score 8):

We all agree that the learning rate can be seen as a way to control overfitting, just like dropout or batch size. But I'm writing this answer because I think the following in Amir's answer and comments is misleading :

- > adding more layers/neurons increases the chance of over-fitting.
  >   Therefore it would be better if you decrease the learning rate over
  >   time.
- > Since adding more layers/nodes to the model makes it prone to
  >   over-fitting [...]
  >   taking small steps towards the local minima is recommended

It's actually the **OPPOSITE**! A smaller learning rate will *increase* the risk of overfitting!

Citing from [Super-Convergence: Very Fast Training of Neural Networks Using Large Learning Rates (Smith & Topin 2018)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.07120.pdf) (a very interesting read btw):

> There are many forms of regularization, such as **large learning rates**,
>   small batch sizes, weight decay, and dropout. Practitioners must
>   balance the various forms of regularization for each dataset and
>   architecture in order to obtain good performance. **Reducing other forms
>   of regularization and regularizing with very large learning rates
>   makes training significantly more efficient.**

So, as Guillaume Chevalier said in his first comment, if you add regularization, decreasing the learning rate might be a good idea if you want to keep the overall amount of regularization constant. But if your goal is to increase the overall amount of regularization, or if you reduced other means of regularization (e.g., decreased dropout, increased batch size), then the learning rate should be *increased*.

Related (and also very interesting): [Don't decay the learning rate, increase the batch size (Smith et al. ICLR'18)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.00489.pdf).

Comment: Hi @Antoine,. I've doubt why people use a small learning rate when fine-tuning the model. As the pre-trained are already prone to overfit.

Comment: Also, in the paper, they have not cited their claim that a low learning rates cause overfitting. They just cited to dropout which reduces the overfitting.