# Should i increase or decrease the loss when model start overfitting

Tags: python, deep-learning, overfitting-underfitting

I am doing image segmentation with a learning rate of `1e-4` and after 80,90 epochs I felt my model starts overfitting.
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51988094/11170350) at StackOverflow suggests that small learning rate leads to overfitting and large learning rate act as a regularizer. On the other hand, we use `reducelronplateau` when model val loss stops decreasing, which is going to a small learning rate.
So I am confused should I increase the learning rate to `1e-3` or reduce it further to `1e-5`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just try both!!

Comment: this is what i have just done, and waiting which one yield better results after 10-15 epochs, but want to listen other people advice